# Underwhelming SSD benchmark results

Tags: ssd, performance

Read benchmarks:

Samsung 850 EVO 250GB, 1 y.o., system drive:

[image: Samsung 850 EVO 250GB read benchmark]

Crucial MX500 500GB, just bought, file storage:

[image: Crucial MX500 500GB read benchmark]

Why such bad results? Especially for the 850 EVO. Isn't it supposed to be around 500MB/sec? Am I missing something? Some parameter in BIOS?

Or is it just maximum for my 8 y.o. P8Z77-V LE motherboard? Drives are connected via SATA6 ports:

[image: photo of the motherboard]

Comment: Are you using SATA 3?

Comment: @harrymc, it's right there in the question: "everything's connected via SATA6"

Comment: In that case it's probably the motherboard that's too slow.

Comment: Are you certain that they are connected via SATA6? Your motherboard specifications mention that the blue sockets are SATA3: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_LX/specifications/ and would explain the speed drop.

Comment: @harrymc, that's what I'm wondering. Is that a thing? Can a mid-tier MB produced in 2012 be too old and slow to reach 500MB/sec or is just something wrong on my part?

Comment: @Mokubai, look for yourself: https://i.imgur.com/9Dae0Qg.jpg

Comment: Around 500 MB/s is only for sequential access. I'm not sure what access does your test.

Comment: @harrymc, oh I see, the test wasn't sequential, it spanned across the whole drive. Run a sequential test, got 500/500 MB/sec for the Crucial drive and 350/150 MB/sec for the Samsung one. Dunno why Samsung sucked so hard, but at least I know now that both the MX500 and the motherboard are fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out, I needed to test for the sequential access - now I'm getting kind of expected results at least for the Crucial MX500.

EDIT: Alright, an here is the reason for the bad EVO 850 performance: [this port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsAU.png) isn't SATA6 even though it's in the row with the actual SATA6 ports